# How to add textview to the left side of the button in android

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

I'm developing the Quiz application in android and I have to display options A, B, C, D inside the button on the left side.

So I know one way, which can be setting the image by drawableLeft property of the button. But putting the four images is not so good.
So I want to know that if there is any other way of doing this may be setting textview inside the button or some other way?

Here is my xml code:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activities.QuizDashboardActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_banner" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_question_no"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                android:text="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:background="@drawable/custom_textview"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/question_no"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_appname" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_appname"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/sansita_one"
                android:text="@string/app_name"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/app_title"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_question"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:text="@string/q1"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="@dimen/question"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_question_no" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_question">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/A"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/button_margin"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/button_margin"
                    android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
                    android:text="@string/q1_a"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/B"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/button_margin"
                    android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
                    android:text="@string/q1_b"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/C"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/button_margin"
                    android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
                    android:text="@string/q1_c"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/D"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/button_margin"
                    android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
                    android:text="@string/q1_d"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black" />


            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is the output:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can add textview at left of the button by giving it an elevation. Set constraints of textview : top to the top of button, start to the start of button and bottom to the bottom of button. And then add elevation, so that textview will be displayed above the button.

Comment: In my case it is not possible to directly apply the constraints to the textview because the button is present inside the LinearLayout.

Comment: So I have to use Constraint laoyut and I have to put the button and textview inside the Constraint Layout and finally put the Constraint  layout inside the linear layout.

Answer (score 1):

Just use LinearLayout instead of a button,set gravity to left, set the option first (A,B,C,D) and then the text view with an answer instead.

No difference visible since you are using custom background for the buttons.

Don't forget to add an OnClickListener() to the new LinearLayout button.